# Prevent sending an opened excel document

Tags: excel, email, document

Is there a possibilty to prevent a user from sending an excel document while it is still opened?

I had to make my document clear certain cells (containing personal data/personally identifiable information). I succesfully did this by using a function that generates a prompt before saving and only saves (and clears the respective fields) when accepting and doesnt do anything when canceling).

However, users can still send the opened document that contains the critical data.

I know it's a stretch, but is there a possibility to prevent this?

Like, with some sort of checksum/encryption shenanigans that corrupts the document while opened, thus rendering a sent copy in this state useless/not accessible/broken. The document would only be "fixed" again when saving (thus erasing the critical data too).

I can only imagine something like this, because forbidding other programs to *read* an opened excel document seems crazy.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

And hello to everyone here! (first post) This place is a lifesaver.

EDIT: For clarification:
1. Users get the excel document. 
2. They enter personal data of staff/applicants etc. into it and my document does fancy stuff.
3. An output is generated which needs to go into some other tool.
4. The excel document's purpose is fulfilled and it must clean itself from filthy personal data.

This is achieved as described before. Saving etc. is all sorted out.

The problem I have been told to deal with, is to make it impossible to send the document while it still contains personal data. Closing wipes it, but while open, it still *does* contain personal data and can be interacted with Outlook etc.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of interaction with the document while still open? Or make the document corrupt while open, so copying it in this state won't transmit any personal data?

Comment: Your question still makes me wonder why you cant clear the sheet after step 2/3 with macro? This way it shouldnt matter if the doc is emailed, right? Anyway, I'm not aware of any way to corrupt a file while it is opened...

Comment: They could still email it before it does fancy stuff. The tool works in a way that you enter all the data first, then press a button to do stuff. Obviously I have to wait till all the data is filled before I do anything with it, let a lone erase it.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome.

Your question is a bit of a strange one and I am not sure what would be the perfect way, but let me try answer and give you some suggestions:

A: You could work with a codeword in a specified cell. When you save a file it will put the word in that cell. When the word is not there.....well, let's say you can create some macro in Workbook.Open event that will delete all cellvalues and saves the file on its current location. Obviously put password on vba coding!

B: A more solid way in my opinion is to work on the file in your personal workspace if possible and upon saving the file create a copy to the shared folder through vba.

Good luck with it.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. This is not quite what I'm looking for. I updated the question with some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

A: Manipulating the checksum/temp encryption would be quite risky since if your code crashes or is halted and closed the file is either corrupt or encrypted for you aswell, so information might be lost.

B: You could make the file copy to a temp while editing.

C: You can maybe block the save/autosave function of excel so that your editing won't get saved half-way in. (Not really a good solution, but a solution, likely quite easy).

EDIT:

For option C:

Insert this to workbook, it runs as it's named, before save.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
//INSERT INSTRUCTION TO REMOVE PERSONAL DATA
End Sub
```

With this, data is removed before file is saved, so any saved state should be clean. Macro-deactivated workbooks however, cannot solve this problem, so you should maybe also add an event at workbook open that unlocks the sheets via VBA to avoid that flaw.

Comment: Understanding the question correct I would say his users can copy or send the file through email. Having the code you suggest triggers when the workbook opens which doesn’t necessarily happen.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify some things. I basically have to prevent sharing/emailing the document while it still contains personal data. Which can only be in an opened state, because saving/closing wipes it.

Comment: Updated suggestion.